# linq-to-sql count of aggregates based on list of IDs

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Consider a table that contains two field: FieldID and Position. Postion is a byte that ranges from 1 to 4.

I'm writing a function that receives of list of FieldIDs and returns the count of items that are in each of the Positions in linq-to-sql. The object that contains the result has 4 fields that contains each of the counts.

This is what I have:

```
public MyObjectModel GetCount(List<int>TheList)
{
   using (DC MyDC = new DC)
   {
     var Result = from t in MyDC.Table
                   where TheList.Select(i => i).Contains(t.FieldID)
                   select new MyObjectModel()
                   {
                      CountP1 = (from t in MyDC.Table
                                 where t.Position = 1
                                 where t.FieldID = ...).Count();
```

I'm having trouble linqing the count based on the list I receive as parameter. Am I approaching this the wrong way? I want to avoid querying each count individually in 4 different queries, each for one count; I'm looking to get the 4 counts in one read. What are your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting an error or just the wrong results?

Comment: @CodingGorilla: for the moment, I'm struggling to get the syntax for the query to generate the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you first group by `Position` and then, in `select` return the count of each group?

Something like:

```
var list = MyDC.Table
    .Where( your filter )
    .GroupBy( item => item.Position )
    .Select( g => new { pos = g.Key, count = g.Count() )
    .ToList();

// list contains items of type ( pos : int, count : int ) where pos is your Position
```

You could even convert it to a dictionary with `key = pos` and `val = count()` so that it's easier to pick values to a model of your choice.

Comment: What should I put in the filter? where t.Position = ??? And what happens to my list of ints? How are tey matched to the data in the table?

Comment: Filter is to select only the data matching your list. Then goes the groupping.